# Shell piping with subprocess in Python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, pipe

I read every thread I found on StackOverflow on invoking shell commands from Python using `subprocess`, but I couldn't find an answer that applies to my situation below:

I would like to do the following from Python:

1. Run shell command `command_1`. Collect the output in variable `result_1`
2. **Shell pipe** `result_1` into `command_2` and collect the output on `result_2`. In other words, run `command_1 | command_2` **using the result** that I obtained when running `command_1` **in the step before**
3. Do the same piping `result_1` into a third command `command_3` and collecting the result in `result_3`.

So far I have tried:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command_1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

result_1 = p.stdout.read();

p = subprocess.Popen("echo " + result_1 + ' | ' + 
command_2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

result_2 = p.stdout.read();
```

the reason seems to be that `"echo " + result_1`  does not simulate the process of obtaining the output of a command **for piping**.

Is this at all possible using subprocess? If so, how?

Comment: See [this example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) for the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @SvenMarnach, would that still allow me to collect the output of the first command in a Python variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
pipe = Popen(command_2, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
pipe.stdin.write(result_1)
pipe.communicate()
```

instead of the line with the pipe.

Comment: This looks great. How would the above change if I want to pipe `result_1` *again* to another command?

Comment: At that point `result_1` is a string. You should be able to repeat the same 3 lines with the new command.